# Union summation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So for the following question: [image: question]

[image]

For $i\in\mathbf Z$ let $A_i=\{i-1,i+1\}$. Determine the following: $$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^5 A_{2i}$$

So when we compute the union of 2i index, how would it affect the range described in Ai to get the answer?

And also, the approach which will work on the above question will also work for the following one, right?

[image]

$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^5 (A_{2i-1}\cap A_{2i+1})$$

Thanks in advance for all the help! :D

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_{2i}$ = $\{2i-1,2i+1\}$, i.e. just substitute $i$ by $2i$.

Therefore for the first union 
\begin{align*}
A_2 &= \{1,3\}\\
 A_4&=\{3,5\}\\
A_6&= \{5,7\}\\
A_8&= \{7,9\}\\
A_{10}&= \{9,11\}
\end{align*}
and the union of all is $\{1,3,5,7,9,11\}$.

In the 2nd example, the union goes of the sections that always yield $2i$, therefore
the result is $\{2,4,6,8,10\}$.

Comment: I have TeXed that for you. Please do it yourself next time.

Comment: Thanks - I would if I could - is there a list of commands / syntax here?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^5 A_{2i} = A_2 \cup A_4 \cup A_6 \cup A_{8} \cup A_{10} $$